# Sequence of monotonic transposition characterisation

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles, symmetric-algebra

Let $\nu$ is a partition on $n$.  Given a $n$ cycle $(1,2,\ldots,n)\in  S_n$.

Let define $H^{m}((n);\mu)$ count the number of tuples $(\alpha,\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_r ,\beta)$  in symmetric group $S_n$ where $\alpha$ is fixed cycle of type $(n)$ and $\beta$ cycle of type $\mu$ and

1) r = len($\mu$)-1 where len() imply length of partition.

2) $$ (1,2,\ldots,n)\tau_1\ldots \tau_r =\beta$$

3) $\tau_i$ are transposition written as $(a_i , b_i)$ and $a_i <b_i$ such that 
 $$ b_1\leq b_2\leq\ldots \leq b_r. $$

For example in $S_5$ 
 elements $H^m(5,(2^2 , 1))$ are collection of monotonic transposition of length 2. 
They are given by

$(1,2)(2,4)$ , $(12)(35)$ , $(13)(34)$ 
this when multiply by $(1,2,3,4,5)$ gives a $(2^2 ,1)$ cycle. Is there is combinatorial characterisation of such sequence? What would be a characteization of such a sequence ?